docker build is generating images under root user when triggered from a jenkins job
Below is the pipeline script to build and push a docker image to the dockerHub. The build step is generating docker images under the root user. and the root user is failing to push the build to the docker registry.
pipeline {
    
    agent any 
    
    environment {
        IMAGE_TAG = "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
    
    stages {
        
        stage('Checkout'){
           steps {
              git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'vooratarun-github-token', url: 'https://github.com/vooratarun/cicd-end-to-end.git'
           }
        }

        stage('Build Docker'){
            steps{
                script{
                    sh '''
                    echo 'Buid Docker Image'
                    docker build -t tarunvoora/cicd-e2e:${BUILD_NUMBER} .
                    '''
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Push the artifacts'){
           steps{
                script{
                    
                    sh '''
                    echo 'Push to Repo'
            
                    docker push tarunvoora/cicd-e2e:${BUILD_NUMBER}
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}


You're missing the step for docker login

Your "user" comments don't quite seem right: since Docker runs as a system daemon, it doesn't really have a notion of an image or container belonging to a specific user.  For simple building and pushing of images, can you use Jenkins's standard Docker support instead of sh 'docker ...' commands?  What is the specific error you get on the push step?

Your pipeline doesn't authenticate with Dockerhub credentials. I run a similar pipeline, here's my syntax:
environment {
        DOCKER_IMAGE = 'example/example:example'
        REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS = 'docker-creds' / or choose different cred name
        DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL = 'https://hub.docker.com/r/example/example'
}

stage('Push Docker Image') {
            steps {
                // Push the Docker image to a registry
                script {
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'docker-creds', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD')]) {
                        sh "echo $DOCKER_PASSWORD | docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME --password-stdin"
                        sh "docker push ${DOCKER_IMAGE}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Make sure you add a credentials entry in Jenkins, type should be "Username and Password", then replace docker-creds with how you named your credentials.
